# Read CSV files in the same order as saved in my directory

Tags: python, pandas, csv

My CSV files are ordered in the following way in the directory:

```
index_dc_20090131
index_dc_20090228
index_dc_20090331
index_dc_20090430
index_dc_20090531
index_dc_20090630
```

I am reading in my csv files via:

```
path = r'myDirectory' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    frame = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = None, header = 0, sep = ";")
    li.append(frame)
```

I assumed `li` will store the files in same order as above, but apparently it is a completely random order. Apparently it has nothing to do with the name or size with the files or the amount of columns they contain.

How can I read the CSV files in so that they are in the same order as in my directory? I would like to avoid having to rename my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't choose files in any specific order. If you want them sorted, you need to sort them:

```
path = r'myDirectory' 
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
all_files.sort()
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    frame = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = None, header = 0, sep = ";")
    li.append(frame)
```